# Joint Probability Density Function of two discrete random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, sampling

The problem I am facing can be described like this:
I have two matrices, as an example, let's assume two sample velocity data which were obtained from bottom of a lake **at an instance t**:

Stream-wise velocity, **A** = \begin{bmatrix}3&3.1&3.2&3.11\\2&2.5&2.58&2.69\\0.1&0.12&0.1&0.15\end{bmatrix}

and

Upward velocity, **B** = \begin{bmatrix}0.4&0.5&0.3&0.1\\0.35&0.2&0.5&0.8\\0.05&0.01&0.05&0.01\end{bmatrix}

their measurement location is defined using **X** and **Y** matrix.

Stream-wise position, **X** = \begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4\\1&2&3&4\\1&2&3&4\end{bmatrix}

and

Upward position, **Y** = \begin{bmatrix}3&3&3&3\\2&2&2&2\\1&1&1&1\end{bmatrix}

So, **the co-ordinate system is located at the bottom of the lake**.

Here's my question: How can I calculate Joint PDF for **A** & **B** in this case? Please describe the process of calculation in details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. How are $A$ and $B$ sampled? What are $X$ and $Y$? Pretend like the reader has never seen the text you are reading when you are phrasing your question.

Comment: I hope the problem is well-defined now?

Comment: I guess you are saying that you've sampled the velocity $v(x, y) \equiv (a(x, y), b(x, y))$ exactly once for each point $(x, y)$. You can't expect to construct a reasonable probability distribution from a single sample. If you sampled it more than once, then you could do something.

Comment: Yes, I have the time series, exactly.

Comment: Then the simplest thing to do is treat each point in time as a sample and construct the [empirical distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function).